# Need help running .jar on Mac

Tags: java

I made a little Java jar I want to be able to run on Macs.
Here's the console error I got on my mac (it's old: Java 6, Osx 10.6).

```html
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257] Exception in thread "main" 
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: SortingMachineColumns : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
8/26/16 3:49:23 PM [0x0-0x21021].com.apple.JarLauncher[257]  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Then I thought: how can I turn this into a mac application? I'm having trouble doing that: I tried [this](https://github.com/UltraMixer/JarBundler), but I don't understand ANT related stuff at all. I tried this, but git kept returning

> /usr/bin/jar2app: line 1: jar2app.py: command not found

So here's my question: How can I get this jar to run? Or how can I turn it into an application?

Thanks!
edit: I changed the compiler to use 1.6. I got the same error message on the console; still didn't work.

Comment: You've compiled your code on Java 8. Java 6 cannot run classes compiled with Java 8.

Comment: This didn't change anything- I got the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are still getting the error message, then you still have classes that are compiled with Java 8 which you are trying to run on Java 6. Make sure you compile your classes so that they can run on Java 6, or upgrade the Java version on the Mac where you're trying to run it on.